# vuejs : My vue component is not rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have a vue component,but when i try to render it,its not render correctly instead shown as html tag
here is component code

view.vue

```
  <template>
    <div>
      <h1>This is  view component</h1>
   </div>
 </template>

<script>
 import Vue from "vue";

    export default {
        name: 'view',
        props: ["store"],
        data:function(){
              return {}
            }
         };
</script>
```

now when i try to render it like below

```
  <div>
      <b-modal ref="my-modal2" hide-footer title="Store Details" class="mt-5">
          <view :store='curStore'/>
      </b-modal>
  </div>
```

[it gives me this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v37V.png)
any suggestion on whats going wrong? thanks in advance

my app mounted using following code

```
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 router,
 template: '<App/>',
 components: { App }
});
```

Comment: is this component inside a vue project or on his own? Why do you import Vue? Where do you mount your application, eg. `id='app'` ?

Comment: this compoennet is part of project,i have module folder named /store inside store i have three files list.vue form.vue and view.vue both other cmponents works fine but view.vue is not rendering

Comment: @wittgenstein i have added code to mount my app

Comment: if your component is inside of a vue project then I would remove the `import Vue from "vue";` and compare how the other components were registered.

Comment: You have to import your component and add it to `components` as well. [Have you checked the Vue documentation?](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration)

Comment:  Good stuff, I'll post it as answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import your component and add it to `components` as well.

Check the Vue documentation:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration

```js
import ComponentA from './ComponentA.vue'

export default {
  // ...
  components: {
    ComponentA
  },
  // ...
}
```

There are nuances for older JavaScript versions. Check the above mentioned link for details.